# How to split this string in dart

Tags: string, dart, split

I have a string **"Salle:C101 Prof:ALa Spe:Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre\Alt\LP_CDTL"**

and I would like to split to have

```
["Salle", "C101"]
["Prof", "Ala"]
["Spe", "Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre"]
```

and tranform it to json

```
[
  {
    "Salle": "C101",
    "Prof": "Ala"
    "Spe": "Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre"
  }
]
```

I know how to transform it to a json, I just need help to split string correctly.

**Edit**

Here's my first try, but I hope there's a better solution.

```
String desc = "Salle:C101 Prof:ALa Spe:Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre\\Alt\\LP_CDTL";

String salle = desc.substring(0, desc.indexOf('Prof') - 1);
String prof = desc.substring(
            desc.indexOf(salle) + salle.length + 1,
            desc.indexOf('Spe') - 1);
String spe = desc.substring(
            desc.indexOf(prof) + prof.length + 1,
            desc.indexOf('\\'));

List<String> salleList = salle.split(':');
String salleKey = salleList[0];
String salleValue = salleList[1];

List<String> profList = prof.split(':');
String profKey = profList[0];
String profValue = profList[1];

List<String> speList = spe.split(':');
String speKey = speList[0];
String speValue = speList.sublist(1).join(':');

print('[$salleKey:$salleValue]'); // Result : [Salle:C101]
print('[$profKey:$profValue]'); // Result : [Prof:ALa]
print('[$speKey:$speValue]'); // Result : [Spe:Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it more simple by using regular expressions. Since there are only one example of your input, it is difficult to design a regular expression there are guarantee to work like your want it but I have made the following example of how you can do it with the example your have provided:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(parse(r'Salle:C101 Prof:ALa Spe:Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre\Alt\LP_CDTL'));
  print(parse(r'Salle: Prof: Spe:Divers Semestre 2\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2'));
  print(parse(r'Salle:AMPHI F Prof:ECa Spe:Bases de la Conception Orientée Objet M2104\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2'));
  print(parse(r'Salle:AMPHI F Prof:JMa Spe:Prog. & administration des Bases de Données M2106\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2'));
}

String parse(String desc) {
  print('Parsing: $desc');
  final pattern = RegExp(r'Salle:(?<Salle>.*) Prof:(?<Prof>.*) Spe:(?<Spe>[\p{L}\d :.,&]*)\\.*', unicode: true);

  final match = pattern.firstMatch(desc);
  final map = {
    'Salle': match.namedGroup('Salle'),
    'Prof': match.namedGroup('Prof'),
    'Spe': match.namedGroup('Spe')
  };
  final list = [map];

  return const JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(list);
}
```

Output:

```
C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --enable-asserts --enable-vm-service:63877 C:\Users\jacob\Documents\GitHub\AdventOfCode2019\bin\status.dart
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:63877/2WFuV1uD4Lg=/

Parsing: Salle:C101 Prof:ALa Spe:Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre\Alt\LP_CDTL
[
  {
    "Salle": "C101",
    "Prof": "ALa",
    "Spe": "Gestion de projet : outils et mise en oeuvre"
  }
]
Parsing: Salle: Prof: Spe:Divers Semestre 2\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2
[
  {
    "Salle": "",
    "Prof": "",
    "Spe": "Divers Semestre 2"
  }
]
Parsing: Salle:AMPHI F Prof:ECa Spe:Bases de la Conception Orientée Objet M2104\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2
[
  {
    "Salle": "AMPHI F",
    "Prof": "ECa",
    "Spe": "Bases de la Conception Orientée Objet M2104"
  }
]
Parsing: Salle:AMPHI F Prof:JMa Spe:Prog. & administration des Bases de Données M2106\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2
[
  {
    "Salle": "AMPHI F",
    "Prof": "JMa",
    "Spe": "Prog. & administration des Bases de Données M2106"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your solution works well with the example I gave.
But as you pointed out, I didn't give enough examples, I'm sorry.
Here are other examples that the string can be.

**"Salle: Prof: Spe:Divers Semestre 2\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2"**
`[
  {
    "Salle": "",
    "Prof": "",
    "Spe": "Divers Semestre 2"
  }
]`

**"Salle:AMPHI F Prof:ECa Spe:Bases de la Conception Orientée Objet M2104\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2"**
`[
  {
    "Salle": "AMPHI F",
    "Prof": "ECa",
    "Spe": "Bases de la Conception Orientée Objet M2104"
  }
]`

Comment: Updated my answer with a modified example so it now works with you new example inputs. Your last example was a little difficult because of the letter é but I fixed it by using unicode syntax where `\p{L}` means "matches any kind of letter from any language".

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. Just one more question. Why isn't it working with this one : **"Salle:AMPHI F Prof:JMa Spe:Prog. & administration des Bases de Données M2106\S2_INFO1\INFO1_S2"**

Comment: Because I did not expect "." and "&" signs in the "Spe" field. I have updated my code again so it now works with your latest example.